# IOS Objective C - Updating NSArray values from another NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `NSArray` with objects Called Houses, each object has 3 fields = id,address,price

I can set the value by using

```
[house setValue:@"£100k" forKey:@"price"];
```

However I have another NSArray called Movements, each object has 2 fields, id & price

so how do I update the 1st array with details from the 2nd array.. in english it I trying to do `"Update house price with movement price where house id = movement id"`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean an `NSDictionary`?  Arrays don't have keys.

Comment: To copy from one array to the other, this is where you'd use what's known as a "loop".  Look it up.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a double loop:

```
for (House* house in houses)
for (Movement* movement in movements)
{
    if (house.id == movement.id)
        house.price = movement.price
}
```

If there will only be one such instance you may want to break early, you'll need an extra BOOL for this:

```
BOOL breaking = false;
for (House* house in houses)
{
    for (Movement* movement in movements)
    {
        if (house.id == movement.id)
        {
            house.price = movement.price
            breaking = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (breaking) break;
}
```

Edit: If you are doing this kind of thing frequently, you probably want to construct a dictionary keyed on the id field so you can look up an object quickly rather than by looping the whole array. NSDictionary is the class you want for this, also note that keys must be objects, so if your id field is an int you'll want to convert it to an NSNumber with `[NSNumber numberWithInt:]` before using it as a key.

Comment: The array is being populated from a core data request. Can this go into NSdictionary ? .. How would your above example look ?  Thanks

Comment: Ah, that's why you were using setValue:forKey: instead of using the accessors directly. Yes, you can store an dictionary of the NSManaged objects, but there are various problems you might encounter like updating it at the right time. I would use the double loop with the break statements and only consider further optimisation if it actually runs slow enough to noticeably lag the UI.